# how to connect mongodb 3.0 in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

When I upgrade my `mongodb` server to version `3.0`  from `2.6` it can't connect from golang use mgo.

I add `'authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1'` in connection string, and it still can't connect to the server. The error that I get is `SASL support not enabled during build (-tags sasl)`

Comment: So is this a runtime error or a compiler error?

Comment: runtime error, it's ok after I reinstall my mongodb server.

Comment: remove mgo package and get again with '-tags sasl' option.
this fixe your current problem.
you may need libsasl2-dev to make the new package.
 `go get -tags sasl labix.org/v2/mgo`
BUT!!! after it i got
 `cannot establish SASL session: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found`
please tell me if you find a way out.

Comment: after install more package to my system, new error message on client `because:server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed. ` and server `AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. Misleadingly I found around the network that has to be included the "labix.org/v2/mgo" package despite the fact that on the official site http://labix.org/mgo (at the time of the reading) it has newer and updated information that points to at least working for me package "gopkg.in/mgo.v2".

I hope this can help since I got to the same steps as you without success and then I have changed the package reference. 
This code worked in my case:

```
  package main

  import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
  )

  //const MongoDb details
  const (
    hosts      = "ds026491.mongolab.com:26491"
    database   = "messagingdb"
    username   = "admin"
    password   = "youPassword"
    collection = "messages"
  )

  func main() {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    session, err1 := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }

    col := session.DB(database).C(collection)

    count, err2 := col.Count()
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Messages count: %d", count))
  }
```

It is also on [Github](https://github.com/Velkata/Golang-MongoDB3.0-Example)

Comment: This didn't help me at all. Still getting auth failed when using DialWithInfo. I have confirmed that all my info is correct as I am able to connect via another client to the DB.

NB: I am using Go1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

change server configurations:

`> var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})`

`> schema.currentVersion = 3`

`> db.system.version.save(schema)`

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17459